# SharePoing Designer Workflow "Impersonation" Question

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, workflow, designer-workflow

I'd like some advice on my workflow as it integrates with MS Access which is causing me some uncertainty.

In terms of impersonation steps, I assume the best way to do this is to use the SP people picker field to accurately identify an individual and their associated credentials. However, what if data is being entered in another method, for instance in an Access field where I don't think I have access to a person picker. Is there any way to use a person's name, or person's email, entered into a DB table and linked to a SharePoint list, to manage the impersonation step?

Basically: How can I use data in my access table to satisfy SP for credential validation purposes?

UPDATE
Ok I think I wasn't clear. Let's drop the Impersonation for a second. I guess this is ultimately a basic permissions question. In SP we use things like the People Picker to select an individual for whom we need to modify permissions. Is there any way for SP to use an existing form field like a Name (Last, First) or Email (rather than person picker) to pick up their associated SP credentials?

Comment: Impersonation steps are run as the person who publishes the workflow. You don't have a setting in the impersonation step to tell it who to run as.

Comment: Can you get the person's user name from their Name or Email?  For example, John Doe for us would be jdoe@company.com and DOMAIN\jdoe.  If that's the case, then you can look up the user from User Profile Services and the workflow can give that person permissions. This is the only way I can think of.

Comment: I did a quick test and it seems to work using just email. If you have a text field providing a user's email, SharePoint seems to recognize and connect that information to their profile, allowing you to use the email to assign identify a SP user. Does this work for you too?

Comment: It does indeed... very cool.  Does this get you all the way to what you need, since you aren't needing the impersonation?

Comment: I may be on the wrong path here, but I assumed I still needed Impersonation Steps in order to gain access to the "Replace List Item Permissions" Action. Currently, my step is setup so that in the Impersonation Step I have a process that checks which user email was input in our initiation form, takes that email and assigns it contribute permissions on the SP Form. Once complete, it revokes the permission for that person.

Comment: Great, it sounds like you've got it.